# Fill form fields dynamically in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

It's a little example of my model:

```
class Food(models.Model):
  food = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  calories = models.FloatField()

class MenuFood(models.Model):
  food = models.ForeignKey('Food')
  amount = models.FloatField()
```

In django admin, when i call template MenuFood i get one ChoiceField with the foods, and TextInput for fill amount, i put extra field in form(TextInput Result).

How can i fill the extra field Result when user select some food or type in TextInput amount or whatever, multiply  calories(class Food) * amount(MenuFood)?

Some idea, thanks.

Comment: You will have to use javascript to make this without submitting the form.

Comment: Ok, the way is, use javascript file, and get the field instance, for make the operations, but i don't know if is hard get field instance in javascript file, yo have any reference, thank's for your help.

Comment: No that's not the way. In your template, include a javascript function that will fire when you choose a food or amount. It must fill your textbox with the value for the user to see (you will have to recalculate the text). In this case it is not necessary to use a separate javascript file

Comment: thank's for your help, i override the template change_form.html, and i get the form.food(is html select), i have event change for get the option, when i get option(in html) i don't know how get the django instance of the option, for get the calories, some idea.

Comment: Easiest way to get the calories is using ajax

Comment: thank's for idea Alvaro, I implement ajax, and everything ok, but i don't know if it's the best way, but work, regards.

Comment: It is the best way, since you are manipulating this data on the client side. Glad it worked